# How to put the widget to rate nodes in a view next to title?

Tags: views, rating

I have a view with the list of nodes, how can I put the widget to rate the nodes next to title?

**Note**: I'm already using the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module. But it returns me only the results.

Comment: Use rate(https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module

Comment: I'm already using this module. But it returns me only the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module, you should configure [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) as shown in this image:

[image]

So what you need to do, is to configure the field "`Votes:Value`". As you can see in my image above, within the ***Appearance*** Dropdown I selected `Rate Widget (compact)`. if you only have "*Rate Widget option or Default*" (as in your comment, it's probably because you have not yet added the required *Relationships* to your view.

Relationships is a way to join tables from another module. To get you going with this also, have a look at the next image:

[image]

Some more details about the 3 (numbered) annotations I added in this image:

1. That's where you add the Relationship, in this case you need to select `Content:Votes`.
2. After you added that relationship, within ***Fields*** you can now add a new field `Votes:Value` (that is: because of the relationship that was added, you'll be able to select this specific field from the list of available fields when you try to add an extra field).
3. After you completed the previous step, automagically in the preview area you'll see a preview of the views results you'll get (don't bother too much about the theming of that preview at this time, what counts is that the result is correct).

Comment: How can I have the rate in a dropdown list?

Comment: what does dropdown list means?

Comment: Something like select list html or input list style

Comment: Change that in Appearance Dropdown

Comment: In Appearence (views form) I have only Rate Widget option or Default

Comment: You have to add relationship in views

Comment: Sorry... relationship with what?

Comment: @Nagarjuna : I "*think*" I understand what you mean (by combining your answer with its comments below it). However, I recommend you somehow integrate (move) the relevant (upvoted) comments into your question. In such a way that you add a few phrases in your answer to tell the reader what you want them to see/notice/do when looking at the screenprint. Just a suggestion ...

Comment: @pierre, thanks for prompting me. Sure no problem as always. And I updated my answer. Cheers :)

Comment: ok, much (let's say 75%) better. But apart from fixing "Relation Ships" (whatever those ships are ... funny!) to "Relationships", do you mind if I expand your answer with a few more lines to add a few more phrases to "document" what is now shown on your images? If you don't like it after I do so, you simply rollback or further refine/adapt it.

Comment: If you can make it better, i am more than happy. It may help somebody

Comment: I'm done, please QA-review, and adapt / rework as you want (worst case: perform a rollback if you don't like my edited version). Ps: I'd be interested to hear from @Daniele if this helps somehow (makes it easier to understand).

Comment: Finaly I find my problem. I have a multi entityes. Votes Relationship doesn't have the option to set  a releationship for him.
How can i do?